# How to get Video / Media Ressouce from flexform with Typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I'm using flexform to select background images for html section elements.

Looks like this:
        dataWrap = |

```
    dataWrap.override.stdWrap.cObject = COA
    dataWrap.override.stdWrap.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.dataWrap = <section class="content {field:flexform_mdCol1} {field:flexform_mdCol2} {field:flexform_col21class}
        20 = TEXT
        20.value = " style="background-image: url(/
        30 = IMG_RESOURCE
        30 {
            file.import.data = field:flexform_mdCol3
        }
        40 = TEXT
        40.value = );">|</section>
    }
    dataWrap.override.if.isTrue.field = flexform_mdCol3
```

Problem is that this doesn't work with Videos. I've created a second field (mdCol4) to select a mp4 Video and mdCol3 Field as poster and background for worst case. Looks like this, but doesn't work.

```
    dataWrap.override.stdWrap.cObject = COA
    dataWrap.override.stdWrap.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.dataWrap = <section class="content {field:flexform_mdCol1} {field:flexform_mdCol2} {field:flexform_col21class}

        20 = TEXT
        20.value = " style="background-image: url(/
        30 = IMG_RESOURCE
        30 {
            file.import.data = field:flexform_mdCol3
        }
        40 = TEXT
        40.value = );">

        50 = TEXT
        50.value = <video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted playsinline poster="/
        60 = IMG_RESOURCE
        60 {
            file.import.data = field:flexform_mdCol3
        }
        70 = TEXT
        70.value = ">

        80 = TEXT
        80.value = <source src="/
        90 = IMG_RESOURCE
        90 {
            file.import.data = field:flexform_mdCol4
        }
        100 = TEXT
        100.value = " type="video/mp4"></video>|</section>
    }
    dataWrap.override.if.isTrue.field = flexform_mdCol4
```

Poster and Background showing up, but it seems IMG_RESOURCE doesn't work for videos and I couldn't find some simuliar.

TYPO3 is 8.7.18. Is this a bug or am I just dumb? :)

Any help is really appriciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the approach and help of Bernd, here is the solution:

```
    dataWrap.override.stdWrap.cObject = COA
    dataWrap.override.stdWrap.cObject {
        10 = TEXT
        10.dataWrap = <section class="content video {field:flexform_mdCol1} {field:flexform_mdCol2} {field:flexform_col21class}

        20 = TEXT
        20.value = " style="background-image: url(/
        30 = IMG_RESOURCE
        30 {
            file.import.data = field:flexform_mdCol3
        }
        40 = TEXT
        40.value = );">

        50 = TEXT
        50.value = <video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted playsinline poster="/
        60 = IMG_RESOURCE
        60 {
            file.import.data = field:flexform_mdCol3
        }
        70 = TEXT
        70.value = ">

        75 = CONTENT
        75 {
            table = tt_content
            select {
                table = tt_content
                uid.data = field:uid
            }

            renderObj = COA
            renderObj {
                10 = TEXT
                10 {
                    data = flexform: pi_flexform:flexform_mdCol4
                }
            }
        }

        80 = TEXT
        80.value = <source src="/
        90 = FILES
        90 {
            files.dataWrap = {field:flexform_mdCol4}

            renderObj = TEXT
            renderObj.stdWrap.data = file:current:publicUrl
            renderObj.stdWrap.wrap = |
        }
        100 = TEXT
        100.value = " type="video/mp4"></video>|</section>
    }
    dataWrap.override.if.isTrue.field = flexform_mdCol4
```

Answer (score 0):

a video is no image.
building an `IMG_RESOURCE`object starts with analyzing the image and resizing if neccessary.

if you just want the url of the file you do not need any image-handling. Just use the public url:

```
90 = FILES
90 {
    // if it is exact one file:
    files = flexform_mdCol4

    // otherwise use references:
    # references {
    #     table = tt_content
    #     uid.field = uid
    #     fieldname = flexform_mdCol4
    # }

    renderObj = TEXT
    renderObj.data = file:current.publicUrl
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I've tried both ways and different variations i found online. But for whatever reason it still doesn't work.

Comment: I found two things. Thanks again. renderObj.data = file:current.publicUrl needs to be renderObj.data = file:current:publicUrl. And if I replace files = flexform_mdCol4 with files = 1177, the file uid, it works. Any Idea what this could be?

Answer (score 0):

just for the art:

I forget to notice you about the possibilities of producing clean code with typoscript.

you have split your wraps in different objects in the array. that is a little bit bad for reading and identifying what should be together.

here my variant of your solution:

*I think there is something missing at `30` (your `75`) as it will render just a list of sys_file uids without usage/wrap.*

```
dataWrap.override.cObject = COA
dataWrap.override.cObject {
    10 = IMG_RESOURCE
    10 {
         file.import.field = flexform_mdCol3
         dataWrap = <section class="content video {field:flexform_mdCol1} {field:flexform_mdCol2} {field:flexform_col21class}" style="background-image: url(|);">
    }

    20 = IMG_RESOURCE
    20 {
        file.import.data = field:flexform_mdCol3
        wrap = <video width="1920" height="1080" autoplay loop muted playsinline poster="|">
    }

    30 = CONTENT
    30 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            table = tt_content
            uid.data = field:uid
        }

        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj {
            data = flexform: pi_flexform:flexform_mdCol4
        }
    }

    40 = FILES
    40 {
        files.field = flexform_mdCol4

        renderObj = TEXT
        renderObj.data = file:current:publicUrl

        wrap = <source src="#" type="video/mp4"></video>|</section>
        wrap.splitChar= #
    }
}
dataWrap.override.if.isTrue.field = flexform_mdCol4
```

notice the changed `splitChar` at `40` so the pipe char can be used as is.